# WinRT - XAML binding DataContext

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, datacontext

I tried to bind `ObservableCollection<UserProfile> UsersList` to pages `DataContext`, but program keeps telling me, that he cannot find `UsersList` although I can see it's values in OutPut using `Debug.WriteLine`.
But on the other hand, if I add `DataContext` in C# code, everything works perfectly.
What am I doing wrong?

C# code:

```
this.DataContext = new UsersViewModel(); //inside MainPage constructor
```

XAML code:

```
DataContext="{Binding UsersViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" //inside <page .../>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>try to set binding this way instead :</s>

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Your current binding means, bind data context to a property named `UsersViewModel` declared in it self. That will work if, for example, you have something like this in code behind :

```
public UsersViewModel UsersViewModel { get; set; }
```

then DataContext will be set to that property.

**UPDATE :**

Looking at your answer, you can try do it this way to set DataContext in Page level :

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:UsersViewModel />
</Page.DataContext>
```

Comment: Yea I tried just now, but still nothing. I even change UsersViewModel object name to something else, to be shure.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your situation. My first snippet works if you want to set DataContext to code-behind. Try to keep your binding as posted and question, and have a property named `UsersViewModel` as shown in my 2nd snippet. Then in constructor initialize the property : `UsersViewModel View = new UsersViewModel();`

Comment: Indeed it works this way also. Great, thanks.
I think, my solution is better, when you wish to bind different objects to diferent elements am I right? But if whole page needs only one binding you can just simply bind to page.

Comment: this approach applicable in object/UI control level also. What makes it different from using Resources is, Resources accessible from multiple controls via it's Key property. So you can bind multiple controls to one viewmodel declared in Resource, can't do that with approach in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it work now, but in this case I don't bind anything on page itself, but on grid.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:UsersViewModel x:Key="UsersViewModel" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" DataContext="{StaticResource UsersViewModel}">
```

Is this good solution?

Comment: that's acceptable I think. Check my updated answer to bind datacontext in page level with similar approach and see if that works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

The UserViewModel should be an accessible object in the MainPage.xaml.cs code behind. You can have something like

```
public UsersViewModel UsersViewModel { get {return _usersViewModel; } private set { _usersViewModel = value;} }
```

You have to use the object name instead of the class name.

Comment: Ok I changed now to: public UsersViewModel View = new UsersViewModel(), but still the same...

Comment: @Klemzy that won't work because you declared it as field/member instead of property. Binding only works with property.